# ytdl-core, node.js, как установить ограничение скорости на скачивания

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, youtube-dl

Мне необходимо скачивать с youtube видео/музыку и сохранять в файл с ограниченной скоростью, например до 128кб.

Может кто показать на примере этого кода - как реализовать ограничение в скорости скачивания.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

ytdl('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ', {filter: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio'})
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.webm'));
```

В консольном варианте ytdl можно передав аргумент -r, либо --rate-limit ограничить скорость, но как тоже самое реализовать в коде...

Предполагаю, что нужно ограничить скорость записи конкретно модуля fs, но ни одного примера не нашел. (99%  плохо искал...)

Comment: `В консольном варианте ytdl ...` -- Вы уверены? В консольном варианте судя по readme в [npmjs у `ytdl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl) есть параметр `--r`, но это сокращение от `--range` (промежуток в видео)

Comment: Вам также стоит ознакомиться с параметром `highWaterMark`, возможно это, то что вам нужно.

Comment: уточните, что именно вы хотите ограничить - скорость сетевого соединения или скорость записи на диск

Comment: @NNL993 range это диапазон видео для скачивания. т.е если необходимо скачать отрывок из видео (если ошибаюсь поправьте).

А что касается highWaterMark то это внутренний буфер в оперативной памяти и его объем никак не влияет на скорость скачивания.

Спасибо за помощь, но пока не то, что хотел.

Comment: @nörbörnën Как пишет пользователь на github скорость скачивание ytdl-core зависит от скорости записи в .pipe, но мне это ничего не дает, ведь как ограничить скорость записи fileWriteStream я так же без понятия.

Но мне нужно конкретно снизить нагрузку на сеть, ведь при скачивании 4гб видео с макс скоростью моего интернета все остальное начинает тормозить, у меня нет потребности скачать быстро файл. Скорость интернета 10мб/c (80мбит/c)

Comment: попробуйте в вызов ytdl, в options указать `dlChunkSize: 0, highWaterMark: 100`. я на тестовых запусках не вижу особой разницы по скорости, но в документации написано так, что именно они должны влиять на скорость (ну, может ещё и liveBuffer, но вряд ли)

Comment: @nörbörnën Попробовать то попробовал, но как и говорил выше, никак это не повлияло на скорость.

Answer (score 0):

По итогу решение пришлось придумывать через костыль. (Как я считаю.)
Изучив документацию потоков nodejs и ytdl-core пришел к такому выводу:

1. Ограничить буфер потока ytdl до 512кб с помощью `highWaterMark: 256 *1024`.
2. Создать пустой записывающий поток. `fs.createWriteStream('test.mp4')`
3. Через Interval каждую секунду с помощью `yt_stream.read(256 *1024)` вытаскивать из потока ytdl по 256кб данных и записывать в другой.

Если кто знает способ проще, то пожалуйста дайте ответ, буду благодарен.

А так вот код, который у меня получился по итогу:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const yt_stream = ytdl('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ', {highWaterMark: 256 *1024});
const w_stream = fs.createWriteStream('test.mp4');
let chunk_buf = 0;

yt_stream.on('progress', (a1, a2, a3) => {
  chunk_buf += a1;
  console.log(`buffer: ${chunk_buf /1024} | chunk: ${a1 /1024} kb (${a1} byte) | total: ${ Math.round( a2/1024 ) } kb (${a2} byte) | of ${ Math.round( a3/1048576 ) } mb | progress ${ (100/a3*a2).toFixed(2) }`);
});

const write_interval = setInterval(() => {
  if( !yt_stream.readable )
    return;

  const chunk = yt_stream.read(256 *1024);
  if( !chunk )
    return;

  chunk_buf -= chunk.length;
  w_stream.write(chunk);
  console.log(`writed: ${ chunk.length /1024 } kb | buffer: ${chunk_buf /1024}`);
}, 1000);

yt_stream.on('end', () => {
  clearInterval(write_interval);
  console.log('end');
});
```